# Magento 1 REST API Gives 404

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento-1.9

I have test magento REST API call i get token.
When i generate Product or customer URL with token it will give 403.

[image]

[image]

This issue is in Local but in LIVE it give 404

Comment: Did you find a solution? @Divya

Comment: No, I have leave it.